# PHP Script not searching

Tags: html, search

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the script is not working properly. I have checked walmart.com code and `name="query"` is correct. I am not sure about the part in `<script></script>`

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.forms[0].q.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="searchForm" action="http://www.walmart.com/search" target="bframe">
<input type="text" name="query" value="" />
<input type="submit">

</form>
<iframe name="bframe" src="about:blank" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What script? There is no script here.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: What does this question have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because walmart.com does not allow you to embed their site in an iFrame. This is obliged by the response header `X-Frame-Options: DENY`.

You can inspect the headers by using cURL, some REST tool or the Chrome dev tools:

Screenshot from Chrome dev tools:

[image: Screenshot from Chrome dev tools]